# CVS login issues - through ant

Tags: ant, cvs

I am trying to do a cvs login through ant using the below target. This is working perfectly under windows, but when I run this on my ubuntu box, I keep getting the authorization_failed error.

```
<target name="cvs_login" unless="cvspass_exists">
   <cvspass cvsroot="${env.CVSROOT}" password="" passfile=".cvspass" />
</target>
```

I have the $CVSROOT variable set in /etc/profile.

```
:pserver:<uname>:<pwd>@<server>:/ABC
```

Am I missing something?

I keep getting this error.

> cvs export: authorization failed: server  rejected access to /ABC for user

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry I think I did not put forward my question in the right way. The ant task was absolutely fine.

I tried the simple cvs login from the command line and it would still ask for my password. That is when I realized that my $CVSROOT env variable was being ignored and cvs was using the pserver settings that were in the CVS/Root file. This file was missing the password, therefore my ant task was failing to login.

After a lot of googling all over the internet, I found that CVS/Root will always take precendence over $CVSROOT. To tackle that, I had to make the below entry in my ~/.cvsrc file.

```
cvs -d :pserver:<uname>:<pwd>@<server>:/ABC
```

And finally, my ant task worked!!. After 3 days of pulling my hair, I have finally figured out the solution. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Can you log into your CVS application from the command line on your Ubuntu box?

I wouldn't bother with the CVS Ant tasks. If you look at the source, you'll see all the cvs tasks are doing is executing `cvs`[command line command directly](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/AbstractCvsTask.java?view=markup). The CVS tasks won't work if you don't have the CVS command line installed. All it does is add an extra layer of hurt to your development task.

Instead, simply call the CVS commands with the `<exec/>` task. This will give you more visibility on what is going on.

Comment: I used direct cvs commands instead of ant task now, to see whats happening.